# email configuration in egroupware

Tags: php

emailadmin-Dependency Failure:(appname: phpgwapi; versions: 1.7,1.8,1.9; appname: egw-pear; versions: 1.8,1.9; ))D

felamimail-Post-install Dependency Failure:(appname: phpgwapi; versions: 1.7,1.8,1.9; appname: emailadmin; versions: 1.7,1.8,1.9; appname: egw-pear; versions: 1.8,1.9; ))P

i am trying to install egroupware locally n my system but i am getting these 2 warning .Because of these warnings i am not able to use mail facility of egroupware. So anybody can tell me how to resolve this warning??

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you have installed the egw-pear. 
Egw-pear is not installed automatically.